# Get single "elements" from a PHP variable

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and don't know much about PHP. I just understand some basics.

I have a `PHP` variable called `$myVariable`. This variable is filled with strings which I loaded from the internal system. I know how to load the strings from the system and this works so far. So my variable looks like this when I try to echo:

```
String1 123 Test
String2 456 Test2
String3 789 Test3
```

etc.

My question now is: How can I work with a single line? I mean if I just want to use Line 1 (String1 123 Test), how can I do that? For example I just want to `echo` line 1. I tried this so far:

```
<?php echo $myVariable; ?>
```

But this echo the whole variable (what is logical). Have I to work with an array or something like this? If yes, can you give me an example?

Thanks in advance

Comment: how is your each line seperated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each line seperated by a new line (if it is not new line replace "\n" with the delimiter)

```
$pieces = explode("\n", $myVariavle);
echo $pieces[0]; //For your first line
```

Comment: If I try to do this, it echo the whole variable again. I thought `[]` is for an array? So I have to make `$myVariable` to an array?

Comment: what you tried can you show? and what is your line delimiter?

Comment: I tried this so far: `$pieces = explode("\n",$myVariable); echo $pieces[0];` `$myVariable` is filled with information which comes from the internal system, I don't think that there is an error because I get the informations

Comment: @Tyler: Add `header('Content-Type: text/plain');` at the top of your script and post the output of `var_dump($myVariable);` in the question.

Comment: So you dont know what your delimiter is. Try  $pieces=explode(PHP_EOL,$myVariable); echo $pieces[0]; Refer to Shankars answer

Comment: If I add `header('Content-Type: text/plain');` I get the `header already sent` error.

Comment: I think I got the error. If I use `print_r($pieces[0])` (refer to @Shankar's answer) I get this:

`Array([0]=> String1 123 Test String2 456 Test2 String3 789 Test3`

So its all in the same array (`[0]`)

Comment: I tested it now with a new file which I didn't load the informations from the system and then it works fine, thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
$arr = explode(LINE_SEPARATOR,$myVariable);
```

so probably its:

```
$arr = explode("\n",$myVariable);
```

You can access every line by $arr[INDEX] where INDEX is line no from 0 to count($arr)-1

Comment: But if I use `[]` I have to use an array, aren't I?

Comment: explode returns array so you have to use [] to access array elements (lines)

Answer (score 3):

Make use of **`explode`** with **`PHP_EOL`**

```
$str="String1 123 Test
String2 456 Test2
String3 789 Test3";

$newarr = explode(PHP_EOL,$str);
//print_r($newarr);

echo $newarr[0]; // "prints" String1 123 Test
echo $newarr[1]; // "prints" String2 456 Test2
echo $newarr[2]; // "prints" String3 789 Test3
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to split your variable.

if your want to split when there are a new line use:

```
$output= preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $myvariable);
```

Else you can use the explode function: https://www.php.net/explode

Comment: You don't have to escape the `\`` if you use single-quotes. Also, it can be shortened to something like ``~\r?\n|\r~``.